# How to Replace + with - in the URL string using code behind or web.config in Classic ASP

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, url-rewriting

I am getting 404 error for the below URL

I want to change this below URL

"http://beta-2.wonderproperty.com/pubs/bars/kingston+upon+thames"

To

"http://beta-2.wonderproperty.com/pubs/bars/kingston-upon-thames"

How it is possible in web.config and codebehind in vb

I have tried to find the string with + in it and replace and redirected the URL but it gives the same error

```
If InStr (lcase (strFullUrl), "+") > 0  Then 
   Response.Redirect ("http://beta-2.wonderproperty.com/pubs/bars/kingston-upon-thames")      
Else
   Response.Redirect ("http://beta-2.wonderproperty.com/pubs/bars/kingston-upon-thames")  
End If
```

I want the URL with plus to be replaced with - like below

"http://beta-2.wonderproperty.com/pubs/bars/kingston-upon-thames"

Comment: The URL `https://www.devtechnician.com/pages/little-paxton` also gives a 404 if it's called in a browser. Why do you expect to get a different result when it's being called "by code"?

Comment: That was a test URL .try this http://beta-2.wonderproperty.com/pubs/bars/kingston-upon-thames